# Android 4.0 on Panda Board - When Installing custom app --> missing shared library

Tags: android, google-maps, adb, pandaboard

I have a panda board and Android 4.0 is running on it. Now I want to install my custom app on the board via ADB but the error `INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY` occurs.
The reason is that my custom app uses google maps and the google apps respectively the google libs a are not integrated in the android build.

1. Is it possible to install the google apps/libraries later?
2. Is it in general possible to bring the google libs to an embedded board or is it not allowed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Google owns the rights to these libraries and I'm pretty sure you need pass the Android Compatibility Tests before Google will officially let you use them on your device (this is what all the device manufacturers have to do AFAIK). It is possible to install the libs unofficially.

In general, I would say Yes to (1) and No to (2) unless you have Google's permission.

However, if your application's main functionality doesn't rely too heavily on Google's services, you can add the line below to your manifest, which will allow you to install the app. However, you will need to account for Google's services not being provided on your device and fallback or disable certain parts of your app.

> <use-library android:name="com.google....."
>   **android:required="false"** />

Comment: The app's main functionality relies on google maps^^ Custom ROMS do  not have the google apps also or? Solves the manual installation of the google maps.apk the error and I am able to install my app?

Comment: Custom roms use an addon package, but AFAIK, this isn't officially supported by Google. You could try your luck with after extracting Google's library from a supported device or a download